# Javascript XMLHTTPRequest Not Posting XML File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

I have a content generator which contians textboxes, textareas and file input controls. All controls are in HTML. Once the save button is clicked I create my XML Document with the text entered into the HTML controls. Finally, I would like the user to be prompted to download the XML File. I am hoping I can do this using a POST method with a XMLHTTPRequest in Javascript. Once the XML Document is sent with the XMLHTTPRequest here is what happens,

Chrome: HTTP Status Code: 304
IE10: Nothing happens

Again, I would like the browser to prompt the user to download the XML File. Here is my code.

```
function generateBaseNodes() {
            var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
                    '<sites>' +
                    '<site>' +
                    '<textareas>' +
                    '</textareas>' +
                    '<textboxes>' +
                    '</textboxes>' +
                    '<images>' +
                    '</images>' +
                    '</site>' +
                    '</sites>';

            if (window.DOMParser) {
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
            }
            else // Internet Explorer
            {
                xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDocument.async = false;
                xmlDocument.loadXML(xmlString);
            }
            return xmlDocument;
        }

        function saveXmlFile(xmlDocument) {

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // IE7+, Chrome. Firefox, Opera. Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else { // IE5 & IE6
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:57326/ContentGenerator.html', true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text/xml');
            xmlhttp.send(xmlDocument);
        }

        $('document').ready(function () {

            $('#templateTab a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                $(this).tab('show')
            })

            //Create TextArea XML elements and add them
            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                var x;
                var xmlDocument = generateBaseNodes();

                $('.content').each(function () { // Textarea

                    if ($(this).attr('id') != undefined) {

                        if ($(this).is('textarea')) {
                            // create article node with control id.
                            articleNode = xmlDocument.createElement($(this).attr('id'));
                            // append node to xmldocument
                            x = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('textareas')[0];
                            x.appendChild(articleNode);
                            // append text
                            articleNode.appendChild(xmlDocument.createTextNode($(this).text()));
                        }

                        if ($(this).is('input[type=text]')) { // Textbox
                            textNode = xmlDocument.createElement($(this).attr('id'));
                            x = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('textboxes')[0];
                            x.appendChild(textNode);

                            textNode.appendChild(xmlDocument.createTextNode($(this).text()));
                        }

                    } else { // Show error if a control does not have an ID assigned to it.
                        alert('The' + $(this).prop('type') + 'has an undefined ID.');
                    }
                });

                $('.imageContent').each(function () {
                    if ($('.imageContent input[type=file]')) {  // Image url
                        // Validate file is an image
                        switch ($(this).val().substring($(this).val().lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()) {
                            case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png':
                                imageNode = xmlDocument.createElement($(this).attr('id'));
                                x = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('images')[0];
                                x.appendChild(imageNode);

                                imageNode.appendChild(xmlDocument.createTextNode($(this).val()));
                                break;
                            default:
                                $(this).val('');
                                // error message here
                                alert("not an image");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });

                saveXmlFile(xmlDocument);
            });
        });
```

### I SUPPOSE I SHOULD POST MY XML OUTPUT

```
<sites>
 <site>
 <textareas>
  <article1>sfdsfd</article1> 
  <article2>dsfsdf</article2> 
  </textareas>
 <textboxes>
  <title>dsfdsf</title> 
  <contentHeader>sdfsdf</contentHeader> 
  <linkContent>sdf</linkContent> 
  <link>sdfsd</link> 
  <relatedContent>sdfsdf</relatedContent> 
  <contentLink>dsf</contentLink> 
  <relatedArticle>sdfa</relatedArticle> 
  <articleLink>sfdf</articleLink> 
  </textboxes>
 <images>
  <imageHeader>C:\Images\Header.png</imageHeader> 
  <articleImage>C:\Images\Main.png</articleImage> 
  <articleImage2>C:\Images\Deals.png</articleImage2> 
  </images>
  </site>
  </sites>
```

Comment: Have you used the developer tools to figure out if the post is happening at all? Or maybe the post is happening but you aren't seeing a response? Why are you posting to an HTML file (ContentGenerator.html)? You should post to a REST endpoint that expects an XML request. Finally, since you are using JQuery, use $.post to abstract away the low-level details of XHR.

Comment: @Vidya I do not have a REST service available. No server-side code base is available to me. I have no problem using the $.post. Will that prompt the user to download the file in the browser? Also, we are fully aware of how unsecure this is.

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you making an ajax request if you have nothing to request to? I am starting to think you are constructing an XML document in browser memory from metadata the user provides and simply wish for the user to be able to get that XML. In that case, just make an iframe with the XML inside, and the user can cut and paste it.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) with `http://localhost:57326/`? **edit** I'm pretty sure that if you're specifying the port, you're not - before any _localhost_ oddities.

Comment: @Vidya Thanks for your reply. Yep! You got it. I had a misconception about AJAX. The XML file is being constructed in memory. The XML nodes are named by metadata, but the textNode contents are actually being taken from the text entered into the textboxes. Is there any way to make the browser prompt to download the XML File?

Comment: @PaulS are you asking if the browser security is set properly to handle this type of action or that it should be set to the actual URL that I am attempting the POST from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the browser prompt to download the XML File?

Yep. Convert your data to *Blob*, then generate a *URL* from it, which you can then use in an `<a>`, give that `<a>` a *download* attribute and the browser now knows it's to be saved not opened, then finally simulate a click on it. For example;

```js
function txtToBlob(txt) {
    return new Blob([txt], {type: 'plain/text'});
}

function genDownloadLink(blob, filename) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    a.setAttribute('download', filename || '');
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filename || 'Download'));
    return a;
}

function downloadIt(a) {
    return a.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
}

// and use it
var myText = 'foobar',
    myFileName = 'yay.txt';

downloadIt(
    genDownloadLink(
        txtToBlob(myText),
        myFileName
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot later and update the post with the outcome.

Comment: This seems to be working, but I am unable to dispatch or add the event listener to <a>.  I receive the following error, "Object doesn't support this action".

Comment: It works in all browsers, but IE. I believe I just have to append the Event in a different way. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to get the user to download a file in memory.

Look also into Data URI's like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#JavaScript):

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,Zm9vIGJhcg==">text file</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Vidya. Unfortunately this JS plugin only supports IE10. I have to support IE8+.

Comment: Oh boy. Yeah the Data URI thing won't work either on IE8. I'm surprised that thing even displays HTML.

Comment: Haha... Just make it go away.